# Avoiding "circular unit reference" when implementing navigation between multiple forms

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-2010, multiple-forms

I have two delphi forms; `frmHome` and `frmStats`. There is a button on the main form (`frmHome`) and when you click on it it takes you to `frmStats`.

On button click in `frmHome`:

```
frmStats.ShowModal;
Hide;
```

This works fine, but on `frmStats` there is also a button that I would like to take the user back to the main form when clicked on. The problem is I get error messages.

If I make reference to the form like this I get the error message "cannot make visable window modal":

```
implementation
uses frmHome_u;
```

However if I make reference like this, then I get the message "circular unit reference":

```
interface
uses  {a bunch of uses} , frmHome_u;
```

On button click in `frmStats`:

```
frmHome.ShowModal;
Hide;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: From the little code you provided I think you are trying to Hide a modal form. frmStats is shown by calling ShowModal(). In the click on frmStats you are doing 2 impossible things:  1.  you try to ShowModal a form that is already Modal,  2  you try to Hide a form that is Modal.   What is it you are trying to do here ? Do you want 2 forms visible and accesable at the same time ? No problem but not with ShowModal.

Answer (score 0):

Modal forms have owners. These owning forms are disabled when the modal form is shown. A form is always shown above its owner.

You are trying to make form1 be the owner of form2 and then in turn have form2 own form1. That circular ownership is not allowed. It would imply that both windows would be disabled, and each window on top of the other.

What you need to do is to close the modal form. Replace

```
frmHome.ShowModal;
Hide;
```

with

```
ModalResult := mrOK;
```

If you want both forms to be visible and enabled at the same time, then you must not show them modally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do then this should work just fine.

```
frmStats.Enabled := True;
frmStats.Show;
Enabled := False; 
Hide;
```

And you have the reciprocal code in the other form.

Because the other form is disabled, it can not be brought into focus until you enable it.

If the users closes FrmStats and FrmHome is the mainform then you must enable it in the onclose event.